# Ignore lint single warning

Tags: android, lint

I'm trying to ignore some lint warning  for a given category, but I do not want ignore all warnings of that category: is it possible? For example I have all the layouts that I use for ListView's rows where on the TextView where I have to show values , I have some sample string that will be replaced at runtime with the proper values, so I do not want to waste time externalizing that kind of strings.
Based on what I see I can ignore only all warnging of a single category, but I just want to ignore some of them.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add translatable=false to your string

like

```
<string name="sampleString" translatable="false">This is a placeholder</string>
```

Comment: I have hardcoded strings that I don't want to translate, that is my problem

Comment: hardcode is a bad idea, you should extract all your place holder strings into donottranslate.xml

Comment: I've explained why I do not want to translate that strings

Comment: yeah, you don't need to translate, just extract them to donottranslate.xml so lint can ignore them.

Comment: I asked for something specific, do you know the solution or not? I know that hardcoding string is not a good practice and already knew about translatable false, but it is not what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was easy: on the lint warnings list, just check the icon "Suppress this error with an annotation/attribute", and that single warning will be ignored.

Comment: specifically lint will put on the TextViews with the hardcoded string the attribute 
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"